# Facebook insights serving JSON with no 'page_fans_gender_age' data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook insights for showing fan page analysis in my application. Since the last upgrade by facebook on 1st week of Oct 2011, i am facing issues with 'page_fans_gender_age' data values served by the Insights API. I am using graph API for this. We fetch the insights JSON on daily basis, but most of the times it do not provide values of 'page_fans_gender_age' parameter. The behavior is random, sometimes it served the required data and sometime it do not.

Anybody facing the same problem?

Comment: has there been any resolution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm facing a very similar problem.

Right now, I'm just simply trying to get some JSON returned from facebook, using JavaScript / AJAX and the GET method.

Are you using the Graph API? If so, how do you attach your extended permissions token to the call to facebook's read_insights?